# Need help by starting/wakeup the API after restarting the ApplicartionPool or the IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI written by C# and hosted on Windows Server Datacenter 2019. The API should be Alwaysrunning and ready and it shouldn't be disposed!

If I stopped the ApplicationPool and started it again, the API doesn't initialize until I send a request or open the URL of the API, then it continues to work.

The problem is, that I have a ScopedService and it should do some work in background and by restarting the AppPool or the IIS, it stops the jobs until a request comes.

I tried a lot of ideas but they didn't work.

I set the AppPool on AlwaysRunning and the Idle timeout of 0 but also didn't help!

I tried also to write a GetMethod to wakeup the API and in web.config I added =>

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="true">
        <add initializationPage="api/app_start" />
      </applicationInitialization>`
```

But also didn't work!

The Application is complete disposed and it wakeup only by calling a method or the URL.

The only method, which has been worked, is to call the API by Shell-Script automatically direct after restarting the IIS using Windows Taskplaner, but it is only workaround and I didn't liked it.

Have anyone any Idea how to do it clean? and initialize/wakeup the application automatically direct if the IIS restarted or the AppPool restarted?

Comment: Is preload enabled on your site advanced settings ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic jinx!

Comment: Yes preload is enabled - @J.Memisevic

Comment: what version of .net you are using ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic I'm using .Net 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation documentation we provide to users hosting our ASP.NET Core 6 application identifies all the prerequisites and steps needed to get the application to launch as soon as the app pool starts or is reset. I'm paraphrasing them here:

**VM Prerequisites**

Installed roles and services (from Server Manager):

- Internet Information Services - World Wide Web Services

  - Application Development Features

    - ASP.NET 4.8
    - Application Initialization

**IIS Configuration**

**Application Pools**

- Start Mode: AlwaysRunning
- Idle Time-out (minutes): 0
- Maximum Worker Processes: 1
- Recycling > Specific Times: 04:00 (4 AM) daily is recommended

This can be done as command line arguments to `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe`:

```
set apppool "AppPoolName" /autostart:true /startMode:"AlwaysRunning" /processModel.idleTimeout:"00:00:00" 
set apppool "AppPoolName" /-recycling.periodicRestart.schedule
set apppool "AppPoolName" /+recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='04:00:00']
```

**Applications**

When adding the site, ensure "Start Website Immediately" is checked:

[image]

Or from the command line:

```
set site "ApplicationName" /applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled:true
```

No additional steps should be needed in web.config or otherwise.

Comment: It's already Enabled but it also didn't work!

Comment: @M.Fakhoury The only other thing I can imagine is that the Application Initialization feature has to be installed on the server. It's not enough just to have it in web.config

Comment: Everything is installed and I tried to put also this =>
   <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="true" remapManagedRequestsTo="swagger/index.html" >
     <add initializationPage="swagger/index.html" />
   </applicationInitialization>

but it didn't work and the API doesn't want to work it shows me the Error => Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop. If I use applicationInitialization - @Emperor Eto

Comment: @M.Fakhoury I updated my answer will all the prerequisites I'm aware of. If these don't work for you something else is going on.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did those steps and now everything works fine :)